# MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate not conform to protocol NSObjectProtocol

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to send an email from my app using `MFMailComposeViewController`I made so:

```
func sendMail() {
        if (MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()) {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients([self.customerMail?.first ?? ""])

        } else {

        }
    }
```

so I've to add the protocol `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` and I made so:

```
extension MyViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

    }
}
```

so why the compiler asked me to add `NSObjectProtocol` if I look at [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontrollerdelegate) I saw that `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` has only one method in his protocol, so why I should add all of these delegate:

```
extension CustomersDetailPresenter: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        <#code#>
    }

    var hash: Int {
        <#code#>
    }

    var superclass: AnyClass? {
        <#code#>
    }

    func `self`() -> Self {
        <#code#>
    }

    func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>! {
        <#code#>
    }

    func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!, with object: Any!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>! {
        <#code#>
    }

    func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!, with object1: Any!, with object2: Any!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>! {
        <#code#>
    }

    func isProxy() -> Bool {
        <#code#>
    }

    func isKind(of aClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
        <#code#>
    }

    func isMember(of aClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
        <#code#>
    }

    func conforms(to aProtocol: Protocol) -> Bool {
        <#code#>
    }

    func responds(to aSelector: Selector!) -> Bool {
        <#code#>
    }

    var description: String {
        <#code#>
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

    }
}
```

What's wrong? And why I should add all of these delegate that I don't need to use? If I've to use this delegate what I should insert in the delegates who need a return value?
Thank you

Comment: Please share `CustomersDetailPresenter`'s code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where ever you use `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`, The class your stating conforms to `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` also needs to conform to NSObjectProtocol.

You can just inherit from NSObject to fix this.

```
class CustomersDetailPresenter: NSObject

class MyViewController: UIViewController, NSObject
```